# can't apt-install any ros packages on RPi debian buster

Tags: raspberrypi, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I've managed to get Ros Noetic (has to be that one as that is what our main PC and robot are running) running on a Raspberru pi 3b (see block below for OS info)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

I have managed to get it to link up at home with my PC running as the master node. and i can see all the nodes running on the network etc. however I can't seem to install any additional packages. As an example I can't even install the tutorials. I'm the mechanical engineer at our company and just trying to learn about ROS so I have some idea of what is going on but this issue has had me stumped for a few hours now and i'd like to work it out while i've got time to play with it this weekend hah!

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-ros-tutorials
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-ros-tutorials
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370663/can%27t-apt-install-any-ros-packages-on-rpi-debian-buster/) by [dmason1992](https://answers.ros.org/users/69004/dmason1992/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you built ROS Noetic from source? If so, you cannot use `apt` to install any additional packages.

Either you install everything using `apt`, or you build everything from source.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dmason1992](https://answers.ros.org/users/69004/dmason1992/) on 2021-01-31**:
Hi, i don't think i did. I followed this tutorial which uses apt-get https://varhowto.com/install-ros-noetic-raspberry-pi-4/

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-31**:
That page is a bit confusing. It has steps to build everything from source as well as `apt` based installs.

You'll have to be specific as to which one you're attempting to follow.

**Comment by [dmason1992](https://answers.ros.org/users/69004/dmason1992/) on 2021-01-31**:
So i used this set of installs

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-rosdep python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool python-rosinstall build- 
essential cmake
```

Which i think is what confused me because the last commands in step 7 look more like building from source

```
   sudo src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space 
   /opt/ros/noetic -j1 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-31**:
Yes, you've built ROS from source with that last command. The first only installs some dependencies which are needed to run the second command.

As I wrote in my initial answer: you cannot use `apt` to install additional packages, you'll have to build them from source as well.

(note: it's not as-if `apt` detects you've built other pkgs from sources and then refuses to work for you. It's that on platforms where you built ROS from source, you typically do that because you don't have any other option, there are no `.deb` pkgs available on those platforms)